# Jenkins and Bitbucket Build not triggering on changes

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I have jenkins job setup for bitbucket on cloud and i have setup SCM poll option in jenkins

I excpected that jenkins will poll Bitbucket and if it detects any change than only it will build but seems like its building everytime when it polls no matter change is there or not.

Am i missing something ?

i tried with enabling "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" too on jenkins but still it builds everytime even if there is no change

I see a webhook trigger for bitbucket which notifies jenkins when checkin happens but i dont have public IP for jenkins server as it is  on internal network

so would like jenkins to poll bitbucket and build only if there is a change is it possible or we require to have jenkins plugin on bitbucket to make it work.

Appreciate your inputs and help

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using build triggers or poll scm? Sounds like you are using build trigger intead of poll scm

Comment: yes i was using "Build when a change is pushed to Bitbucket" only

Answer (score 0):

I have 
1. Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket [ check]

But when a new file is checked in in Bitbucket it was not detecting the change
seems like i also need to enable Poll SCM and set the schedule

When i checked Poll SCM and scheduled it for  every minute in polling log now i can see it trying to scan the changes

Thanks